# How can I get consistent results in plain Kotlin and Kotlin on Android when parsing malformed numbers?

Tags: android, kotlin, number-formatting

I'm facing inconsistencies between Kotlin on Android and Kotlin in the tests when using `java.text.NumberFormat` for parsing a malformed number:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat
import java.util.Locale

val value = "1,1.90.00"
val parsed = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).parse(
    value
)
```

On plain Kotlin this results in `11.90`, but using Kotlin on Android this results in `1`

Is there a way I can get a consistent result when parsing invalid numbers? The code should be used for user input validation / correction, so I don't have any control over the user inputs themselves.

The difference be seen here, where the jetpack compose preview (the last one) differs from the emulator execution:

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun PreviewNumberFormatConversion2() {
    val value = "1,1.90.00"
    Column {
        Text("Original: $value")
        val parsed = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).parse(
            value
        )
        Text("Parsed: $parsed")
        val rounded = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).apply {
            maximumFractionDigits = 2
            minimumFractionDigits = 2
            minimumIntegerDigits = 1
        }.format(
            parsed
        )
        Text("Rounded: $rounded")
    }
}
```

[image]

I did not really try solving the issue myself as I don't have a clue where to start. The only workaround I could come up with was to not care about the result of such obscure inputs, but I would still like to make the corrections consistent between unit tests and instrumented tests...

Comment: Please check whether the Java version of Kotlin is consistent. Is the internal implementation of java.text.NumberFormat inconsistent in different Java versions?

Comment: I feel like Halifax is right, and this is down to different versions of Java displaying different kinds of undefined behaviour. Like you say the input is malformed, so it's going to fail to parse at some point - on one version it's failing at the duplicate decimal point, on the other it's failing earlier at the misplaced grouping separator. I feel like it would *make sense* that a newer version of Java is more forgiving about that separator, like its ability to parse a number has been broadened. All the documentation for `parse` says is the whole string may not be used

Comment: With this basically being invalid input producing invalid output, maybe it would be a better idea to just detect when parsing is incomplete (e.g. using the methods that update the index of a `ParsePosition`) and count that as a general failure? Instead of relying on specific output from a failed parse - there doesn't seem to be a guarantee of any consistent behaviour there